# API test on DHC id show null

Tags: api, rest, post, dhc

when I test my rest API in DHC chrome extension, it shows on post method id is null. what will be reason for this? please suggest a solution.

```
{ "status": "200", "id": null, "email_exists": false }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server returned `null` for `"id"` or it's DHC bug. You can switch response body view on `Raw` response view, just click on `Pretty` combo at right to verify what the server has really returned.

Don't hesitate to contact DHC support here: dhc@restlet.com